# Citrus XPath Validation Cannot Find Element

Tags: java, xml, xpath, citrus-framework

I have an XML payload with the element `ValidationFault`. Part of my validation is to confirm the `ValidationFault` element occurs only once in the XML payload. Using the following Citrus Java DSL:

```
runner.receive(action -> action.endpoint(endpointName)
      .validate("number://ValidationFault", 1));
```

I do not get back the expected value of 1, instead 0:

```
com.consol.citrus.exceptions.TestCaseFailedException: Validation failed: Values not equal for element '//ValidationFault', expected '1' but was '0'
```

I have manually confirmed that the response payload does contain the element in question. I also validated the XPath with an external tool and found that the XPath should be correct. I have tried with the namespaces as well, `//soapenv:ValidationFault` and `//:ValidationFault`, but I receive the same exception.

## Edit:

This is the XML payload that is received (with some data removed):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
             xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
     <env:Header/>
     <SOAP-ENV:Body
              xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
              xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
              xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
     <soapenv:Fault>
         <faultcode>soapenv:Client</faultcode>
         <faultstring>ValidationFault</faultstring>
         <faultactor>GetSalutation</faultactor>
         <detail>
             <ValidationFault
                 fault:retryable="false"
                 xmlns="http://domain/fault/2.0/"
                 xmlns:fault="domain/fault/2.0/">
             <ErrorCode>flt-00001</ErrorCode>
             <DescriptionText>A Schema Validation Failed</DescriptionText>
              <Details>
                  <Text></Text>
              </Details
              <TransactionControlIdentificationID>
                  TBD
              </TransactionControlIdentificationID>
              <ZuluDateTime><ZuluDateTime>
          </ValidationFault>
      </detail>
  </soapenv:Fault>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: `ValidationFault` (and all of its descendants) are in the default namespace `http://domain/fault/2.0/`. Maybe this will help: http://citrusframework.org/citrus/reference/html/index.html#default-namespaces-in-xpath (I'm not familiar with the citrus framework.)

Comment: I suspect it might be caused by namespaces, but handling default namespace with`//:ValidationFault` did not solve the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a namespace context that declares the namespace prefixes for the Xpath expression evaluation:

```
receive(action -> action.endpoint(fooChannel)
        .namespace("ns", "http://domain/fault/2.0/")
        .validate("number:count(//ns:ValidationFault)", 1));
```

The Xpath expression evaluates to the node values by default. So please make sure to use `count()` function in order to evaluate the number of elements.

As an alternative to that you could evaluate to the node-set and use the Hamcrest matcher `hasSize()`:

```
receive(action -> action.endpoint(fooChannel)
        .namespace("ns", "http://domain/fault/2.0/")
        .validate("node-set://ns:ValidationFault", Matchers.hasSize(1)));
```