# How to validate an optional json value

Tags: json, citrus-framework

I try to validate a json response (just like in the example below from the website), but I fail on validation optional elements. I can only validate mandatory elements with 'validate', because if the json-path failes, it already counts as failed.

Can anybody get me a **hint on how to validate** a value, **IF AND ONLY IF** the element exists? If it does not exist (optional), it is good also...

*Example if have to validate*:
The description is optional, but if it is set, it should not be longer than 30 characters.

```
http()
    .client(todoClient)
    .receive()
    .response(HttpStatus.OK)
    .messageType(MessageType.JSON)
    .validate("$.id", "${todoId}")
    .validate("$.title", "${todoName}")
    .validate("$.description", "${todoDescription}");
```

Answer (score 0):

May be this post can help you, there is the use of `Matchers.` 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/50817190/11770752

First you can try `Matchers.hasValue`, if so you check with `Matchers.hasSize`.

Otherwise i found the `.jsonPath(String jsonPathExpression, Object controlValue)` after `.messageType(MessageType.JSON)` but i don't know if it does check for optionals or even validates the Json Value.

EDIT: As is was browsing the Documentation there is the option of Validation Matchers in Citrus. http://citrusframework.org/reference/html/index.html#validation-matcher

Replace `"${todoDescription}"` with `"@matches('\w{30}')@"`, it should work.